# How can I remove the Reading List column in Safari?

Tags: safari

How can I get rid of the Reading List column in Safari when I read a webpage?  It takes up too much space on the page.

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=hide+reading+list+safari

Answer (score 8):

Select View > Hide Reading List, press ⇧⌘L, or press the button on the bookmark bar.

[image]
[image: 2]

Comment: This is View > Hide Sidebar in Safari 14.1.1

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in Safari's preferences.

[image: Safari Preferences]

Comment: The bookmark tab is not available in safari 9.1

Comment: Who said anything about bookmarks tab?

Comment: Don't you see the bookmark tab clicked in your screenshot?

Comment: Duhhhh there are other options ticked as well.

Comment: Who said anything about options ?